# Responsive Slides - Not sliding equal times

Tags: jquery, slideshow, responsive-slides

I am using the responsive slides plugin (http://responsiveslides.com/) on my site. I have set the following options:

```
 jQuery(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  speed: 100,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
  timeout: 10000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
  pager: false,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
  nav: true,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
  random: false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
  pause: true,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
  pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
  prevText: "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
  nextText: "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
  maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
  navContainer: "",       // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
  manualControls: "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
  namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
  before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
  after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
});
```

However, the first slide shows for a lot longer than the others. Does anyone know why this might be and how I can fix it?

You can see the slide at http://www.hbprojectsltd.co.uk/testimonials

Thanks!

Comment: Check your page, you have some errors. You are starting functions with a "jQuery".

Comment: I have removed the files that were causing the errors. I use 'jQuery' to start functions with as I was getting error $ is not defined. The result is still the same... still sticking longer on 1st slide... :(